# How to rotate pages completely

Tags: adobe-indesign, rotate

I just started out using indesign and I struggle with very basic things sometimes because I never really "learned" them. I usually just google them and that works out just fine. But this one is probably so easy noone ever asked it before so I'll just try asking you guys :)

I have to rotate a few of my pages in several documents because my printer can't do my current measurements. Rotating the pages with the option "document set up" doesnt change the layout, the "layout setup" option changes, well, the layout lol and rotating things manually would take way too long (I would have to work very precisely, I tried it, It worked ofc but I'd really like to know a faster method)

Thank you for reading this, I appreciate it 
Abby

Comment: I'm sorry, what? If you need to alter the dimensions of pages, you change the document setup, then alter the elements on the page. That's how it's done. If it "takes too long" there's nothing you can do about that but bear down and do it. Again, that's how it's done. This is why proper document dimensions at the start of a project are often critical.

Comment: "rotating the document to print" and "changing the layout to fit a different proportion" are very different things. Please [edit] your question to make it more clear what's the problem you need help with.

Comment: I'm also curious how rotating the pages changes what your printer can do.... 8x10 is the same as 10x8.... rotation doesn't alter printer capabilities. If you are referring a something like a home, end-user, printer such as an inkjet.. you can tell that type of printer to rotate pages on output in the print dialog window. There'd be no need to actually change an InDesign file.